API controller class for all tables
I'm creating an EF Core API to connect my MAUI app to my SQL Server database.
This is my tblUser table's controller (Select, Create, Update, Delete, all the usual stuff) in the API:
‌
UserController:
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class tblUserController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly QDbContext _qDbContext;

    public tblUserController(QDbContext qDbContext) => _qDbContext = qDbContext;

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult<IEnumerable<tblUser>> Get()
    {
        return _qDbContext.tblUsers;
    }

    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<tblUser?>> GetById(int id)
    {
        return await _qDbContext.tblUsers.Where(x => x.ID == id).SingleOrDefaultAsync();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Create(tblUser user)
    {
        await _qDbContext.tblUsers.AddAsync(user);
        await _qDbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

        return CreatedAtAction(nameof(GetById), new { id = user.ID }, user);
    }

    [HttpPut]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Update(tblUser user)
    {
        _qDbContext.tblUsers.Update(user);
        await _qDbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        return Ok();
    }

    [HttpDelete("{id}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Delete(int id)
    {
        var userGetByIdResult = await GetById(id);
        if (userGetByIdResult.Value is null)
            return NotFound();

        _qDbContext.Remove(userGetByIdResult.Value);
        await _qDbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        return Ok();
    }
}

I really didn't want to repeat the same thing for each table, so I made a parent class that gets the type as TEntity and does the same stuff:
DbController:
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class DbController<TEntity> : ControllerBase where TEntity : class
{
    private readonly DbContext _context;
    private readonly DbSet<TEntity> _dbSet;

    public DbController(DbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
        _dbSet = _context.Set<TEntity>();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<TEntity>>> Get()
    {
        return await _dbSet.ToListAsync();
    }

    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<TEntity>> GetById(int id)
    {
        TEntity? entity = await _dbSet.FindAsync(id);
        return entity == null ? (ActionResult<TEntity>)NotFound() : (ActionResult<TEntity>)entity;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Create(TEntity entity)
    {
        _ = await _dbSet.AddAsync(entity);
        _ = await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return CreatedAtAction(nameof(GetById), new { id = entity.GetType().GetProperty("ID")?.GetValue(entity) }, entity);
    }

    [HttpPut("{id}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Update(int id, TEntity entity)
    {
        TEntity? existingEntity = await _dbSet.FindAsync(id);

        if (existingEntity == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        _context.Entry(existingEntity).CurrentValues.SetValues(entity);
        _ = await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return Ok();
    }

    [HttpDelete("{id}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Delete(int id)
    {
        TEntity? entity = await _dbSet.FindAsync(id);
        if (entity == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        _ = _dbSet.Remove(entity);
        _ = await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return Ok();
    }
}

And I inherited my UserController from it:
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class tblUsersController : DbController<tblUser>
{
    public tblUsersController(QDbContext context) : base(context)
    {
    }
}

I have a API.Client project to connect to the API, it has a client service class that works fine:
DbApiClientService:
namespace QF.API.Client
{
    public class DbApiClientService
    {
        private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;

        public DbApiClientService(ApiClientOptions apiClientOptions)
        {
            _httpClient = new HttpClient();
            _httpClient.BaseAddress = new System.Uri(apiClientOptions.ApiBaseAddress);
        }

        public async Task<List<T>?> GetItems<T>()
        {
            string endpoint = GetEndpointName<T>();
            return await _httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<List<T>?>($"/api/{endpoint}");
        }

        public async Task<T?> GetById<T>(int id)
        {
            string endpoint = GetEndpointName<T>();
            return await _httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<T?>($"/api/{endpoint}/{id}");
        }

        public async Task SaveItem<T>(T item)
        {
            string endpoint = GetEndpointName<T>();
            await _httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync($"/api/{endpoint}", item);
        }

        public async Task UpdateItem<T>(T item)
        {
            string endpoint = GetEndpointName<T>();
            await _httpClient.PutAsJsonAsync($"/api/{endpoint}", item);
        }

        public async Task DeleteItem<T>(int id)
        {
            string endpoint = GetEndpointName<T>();
            await _httpClient.DeleteAsync($"/api/{endpoint}/{id}");
        }

        private string GetEndpointName<T>()
        {
            return typeof(T).Name;
        }
    }
}

The problem is that when I use the API with the "parent" class, I get a 404 error, although swagger works fine! Rolling back out of the parent class in the API makes it work again.

I can't see anything named GetItems? Which method did you mean? How you are calling the endpoint?

This is the "Repository of T" pattern for simple literal CRUD  ("Repository" pattern is for DB ops that reflect specifics of biz logic requirements). As such it works for simple cases, but then becomes a blocker for richer logic  (eg. start needing transactions to work around every entity doing a separate save when EF could do one save),.  Huge problem if you don't want to send the entire entity (maybe not all users should see everything) TL/DR: it is a naïve approach that is a quick win for easy cases. All IMHO, learned through experience.

I have made similar thing but throughout the development I start to need to add lots of code to handle many special case, resulting in a failing abstraction. Because everything is done at controller, it also made unit test difficult to write. There also won't be auto generated API document either, so it'd be a huge pain for both users and your future self when debugging. Maybe a generator for all the controllers to generate everything at once, so repetitive workload is decreased, but the code structure is still correct and you can change anything easily anytime.

@MdFaridUddinKiron sorry I mixed up stuff from this headache. I edited my post.

If all your API does is access your DB with more code required you should be using a DB that´s designed to be accessed from clients directly and scrap the backend imo (firebase comes to mind). Either way your abstraction seems like a bad idea to me.

@Max not a good idea to access the db directly from client device, is it?

Depends on the DB.

"Depends on the DB" depends on the infrastructure's abstraction. otherwise you shouldn't

Probably, bit too opinionated for SO. Sure "it depends". Just giving food for thought that a backend might be overkill if all you are doing is CRUD with zero logic. There are DBs such as firebase that are designed to be used without a backend. You should not do this with any DB. But mainly I do not think the abstraction choosen is good at all, in any design (to the point I question the program has to exist at all => "do you really need a backend?"). For similar reasons as @Richard already tried to articulate. It´s an abstraction that becomes a nuisance given the simplest requirement changes.

@ParSa 1) that's the "Fake Repository" antipattern - a CRUD class over the high-level Unit-of-Work that is DbContext. DbContext is neither a connection nor a database driver. 2) The overall idea is identical to OData and GraphQL and fails badly if you allow clients to run any query they want. The first versions of OData simply died because they allowed that. Which means that 3) What you ask is already implemented in various libraries, including HotChocolate and the latest versions of ASP.NET Core OData. And NO YOU DON'T want one controller for every Entity

@ParSa finally, Microsoft created Data API Builder to expose entities from database tables as both OData and GraphQL entities with with a bit of configuration, storing entities in settings files and using generic GraphQL/OData code. The docs push the "Azure" aspect of this but nothing prevents you from running the tool locally. And if you want to see how this works, you can check the code in Github

@PanagiotisKanavos thanks but i'm way too deep in my own api to convert into OData and test and handle everything from scratch...
